# Can't find the variable "SSL" javascript

Tags: javascript

ERROR: Can't find variable SSL

Good morning, I was finishing the script when I find a problem that I couldn't solve. When I click on a button, it tells me can't find the variable "SSL" but it is created (just show the error when I click one button), can you tell me if there are some misstake?
html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>SSL Checker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json.json" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body onLoad="start()">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>SSL Checker</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="data">
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="SSL.Add()">
            <input type="text" id="add-name" placeholder="Name"></input>
            <input type="text" id="add-link" placeholder="Link"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>

        <div id="edit" role="aria-hidden">
            <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="saveEdit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-name">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> <a onclick="CloseInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <p id="counter"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="table">
        <table style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <tr>
                <th>Sites:</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="urls">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

js:

```
    function start() {
var SSL = new function() {
            //List urls to check
            this.el = document.getElementById('urls');

            this.Count = function(data) {
                var el = document.getElementById('counter');
                var name = 'url';

                if (data) {
                    if (data > 1) {
                        name = 'urls';
                    }
                    el.innerHTML = 'There are:' + ' ' + data + ' ' + name;
                } else {
                    el.innerHTML = 'No ' + name;
                }
            };
            //Buttons configuration
            this.FetchAll = ss =function() {
                var data= '';

                if (MyJSON.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < MyJSON.length; i++) {
                        data += '<tr>';
                        data += '<td><a href="' + MyJSON[i].url + '">' + MyJSON[i].name+ '</a></td>';
                        data += '<td><button onclick="SSL.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>';
                        data += '<td><button onclick="SSL.Delete(' + i + ')">Delete</button></td>';
                        data += '</tr>';

                    }
                }

                this.Count(MyJSON.length);
                return this.el.innerHTML = data;
            };
            //Add name
            this.Add = function() {
                el = document.getElementById('add-name');
                el1 = document.getElementById('add-link')
                var url = el.value;
                var url1 = el1.value;
                if (url) {
                    MyJSON.name.push(url.trim());
                    el.value = '';
                    this.FetchAll();
                }
                if (url) {
                    MyJSON.url.push(url1.trim());
                    el1.value = '';
                    this.FetchAll();
            }
            }

            //Edit
            this.Edit = function(item) {
                var el = document.getElementById('edit-name');
                el.value = MyJSON.name[item];
                document.getElementById('edit').style.display = 'block';
                self = this;
                document.getElementById('saveEdit').onsubmit = function() {
                    var url = el.value;
                    if (url) {
                        self.urls.splice(item, 1, url.trim());
                        self.FetchAll();
                        CloseInput();
                    }
                }
            };
            //Delete
            this.Delete = function(item) {
                MyJSON.name.splice(item, 1);
                this.FetchAll();
            };

        }

        SSL.FetchAll();

        function CloseInput() {
            document.getElementById('edit').style.display = 'none';
        }
}
```

Comment: `SSL` is inside `start`, so it's not global. Consider attaching listeners properly in Javascript instead and it won't be an issue.

Comment: As mentioned by @CertainPerformance, the SSL variable is local to the `start` function. As a quick hack, you can do `window.SSL = SSL` at the end of `start` but a better way to do that would be to use Javascript Event Handlers properly. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: Hello,  thanks for your help, I solved it but now when I try click some button it tells me : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'MyJSON.name.push')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the variable SSL was into start so, it wasn't global variable.
I needed to do window.SSL = SSL and It works.
Thanks you CertainPerformance and @Chriag Ravindra